# Need help in simple sql to add record

Tags: php, mysql, sql

We use (INSERT INTO) to insert a record in the table which creates more than one record when used again. Is there any way to add a record and alternately replacing the prevoius one without adding any new record.
I know this would work:

```
UPDATE Customers
SET ContactName='Alfred Schmidt', City='Hamburg'
WHERE CustomerName='Alfreds Futterkiste';
```

But what if there is no condition ie. we don't know the record, we only know the column name. Is there any way to fill only one record and alternately replace the previous record without creating 2nd record?

Comment: Any UPDATE without a condition will update all rows in the database. You could write a procedure.

Comment: if you don't have a condition, how do you know what the previous record is?

Comment: ...so remove the `WHERE` line

Comment: `REPLACE` might be the solution https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Comment: @karan, without a condition, how would you know which row to remove/replace?

Comment: or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Are you saying you only ever want 1 row in the Customers table?

Comment: There is only one row
the reason I wat to replace is that I only want one row

Comment: yes, you are right @Dean

Comment: Yeah... in that case, @PatrickReck was correct: remove the `WHERE` line.  Of course, that assumes you already have 1 row in this table.  If you want to make it work with 0-1 lines you could wrap it in an `IF`.  Though I would have to question why you are doing this.  And why is your table named `Customers` when there can only ever be one customer? ;)

Comment: That's an example. I have a div content in a HTML page which contains Quote of the Day. Using Database I'm replacing the quote of the day @Dean

Comment: It's not working. It gives error: Error: Erreur de syntaxe près de '('sasasa','saas@asa.com',' saassa')' à la ligne 2 @dean

Comment: You need to use what @Fred-ii- suggested. You need a unique key for that, so INSERT will check if there is a matching key during the insert - which would be CustomerName - and update the other 2 fields on a match. If not, it will create the new customer record. You need to add unique index on CustomerName and of course there will be no customers with the same name in this case. SQL will look like INSERT INTO Customers (ContactName, City, CustomerName) VALUES ('Alfred Schmidt','Hamburg', 'Alfreds Futterkiste') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ContactName='Alfred Schmidt', City='Hamburg'; No WHERE needed

Comment: @smozgur [Seems they've found their solution after all...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30201051/)

Answer (score 1):

OK... updating if a record exists or creating a record if there are zero records is a pretty simple matter and you have a solution for it.  That having been said, I would do something different and keep track of my message of the day by date:

```
-- This is REALLY BASIC, but, just to give you the idea...
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MessageOfTheDay](
    [MessageDate] [date] not null,
    [MessageContents] [nvarchar](500) not null,
    UNIQUE (MessageDate)
)

declare @MessageContents nvarchar(500), @MessageDate date
set @MessageContents = 'This is the new MOTD!!!'
set @MessageDate = GETDATE()

-- Every day, create a new record and you can keep track of previous MOTD entries...
insert into MessageOfTheDay(MessageDate, MessageContents)
values (@MessageDate, @MessageContents)

-- Get the message for today
select MessageContents from MessageOfTheDay where MessageDate = @MessageDate

-- If you want, you can now create messages for FUTURE days as well:
set @MessageContents = 'This is tomorrow''s MOTD!!!';
set @MessageDate = dateadd(D, 1,GETDATE())

insert into MessageOfTheDay(MessageDate, MessageContents)
values (@MessageDate, @MessageContents)

-- Get tomorrow's message
select MessageContents from MessageOfTheDay where MessageDate = @MessageDate

-- If you aren't necessarily going to have one per day and want to always just show the most recent entry
select MessageContents from MessageOfTheDay order by MessageDate desc limit 1
```

Anyway, that's just my $.02.  At some point I bet you will want to look over the history of your MOTD and when you do, you will be happy that you have that history.  Plus, this more accurately models the data you are trying to represent.

Comment: Can you come on team viewer for a minute? @Dean

Comment: Is one of those queries giving you problems?

Comment: Yes, I'm unable to understand. Are you on facebook or twitter or something like that where I can contact you?

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer and It's working now!
I used:

```
INSERT INTO data (a, b, c)
VALUES
('1','2','3')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(a)+VALUES(b)
```